# C# winforms label.size not truncating label text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have label which contains text obtained from the user's local machine *-- edit -* and text length is neither fixed nor predictable. It was added to the form using VS designer and is AutoSize = true. If the width of the label exceeds 260 I want to switch to fixed width/AutoEllipse.  When the label width exceeds the max limit, however, instead of truncating the text, the text continues to the edge of the form (and probably beyond that, actually).  From what I've read the MaximumSize, AutoSize and AutoEllipse don't work together.  Code I'm using:

```
        string maxDesc = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing";
        int destW;
        int destWmax;

        DestNameLBL.Text = maxDesc;
        destW = DestNameLBL.Width;
        if (destW >= 260)
        {
            destWmax = 260;
            DestNameLBL.Size = new Size(destWmax, 16);
            DestNameLBL.AutoEllipsis = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DestNameLBL.AutoSize = true;
            destWmax = destW;
        }
```

I can achieve my objective by creating a control programmatically:

```
        Label destDesc = new Label();
        destDesc.Location = new Point(100, 119);
        destDesc.Text = maxDesc;
        destDesc.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, FontStyle.Regular);
        if (destW >= 260)
        {
            destWmax = 260;
            destDesc.Size = new Size(destWmax, 16);
            destDesc.AutoEllipsis = true;
        }
        else
        {
            destDesc.AutoSize = true;
            destWmax = destW;
        }
        Controls.Add(destDesc);
```

The sets of code are essentially identical.  Why is this working with a programmatically created control but not with the control added via the designer (or is that even the relevant differentiation)?

Comment: it doesn't look like you are turning off `AutoSize`

Comment: I would doubt that a Label instantanous updates its width upon setting the Text property. So this line `DestNameLBL.Text = maxDesc;` won't change the width immediatly.

Comment: `AutoSize = true` is applied by the default LayoutEngine (this Control calls `SetSelfAutoSizeInDefaultLayout(this, true)` in its Constructor). It's *automatic* when you add a Control to a container in the designer. When you add a Control in code, `AutoSize` is not applied (there's no LayoutEngine yet), so it acts as `AutoSize = false`.

Comment: Just set the MaximumSize property.  You much prefer to do so in the designer so it gets automatically scaled by the monitor dpi.

Comment: @Daniel - I presumed programmatically setting the Size would override the designer property but obviously that's not valid.  Explicitly setting AutoSize=false did the trick.  Thanx -- if you'd create an Answer I can mark this solved ...

Comment: @Hans My understanding is MaximumSize has no relevance with a fixed size and fixed size is required for AutoElllipse; did I misread the documentation?

Comment: @Rand I'm not sure how instantanious the change is but it is occurring prior to displaying the window using Daniel's suggestion.

Comment: @Jimi - actually taking your comment in conjunction with Daniel's fully answers my question.  For my future reference what's the protocol here when it is the combination of two comments that causes the ""Ah-Ha" light bulb to click on?

Comment: AutoEllipsis kicks in when the text does not fit the control.  So when the MaximumSize is too small.  Very easy to test in the designer, no code required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on multiple comments above.]

A label placed on a form in VS designer with AutoSize=true does not have the AutoSize automatically overridden when programmatically setting the control to a fixed size.

It must be explicitly overridden.

AutoSize default for controls added in designer is true but for controls defined "in code" the default is false.  Therefore identical code may behave differently depending on how the control is added.

Using MaximumSize and AutoEllipsis together will truncate display of the text with the ellipsis BUT (in my testing) will not show the ToolTip containing the complete text on MouseOver.

This code is working for truncating with ellipsis and ToolTip

```
        string maxDesc = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit";
        int destW;
        int destWmax;

        DestNameLBL.Text = maxDesc;
        destW = DestNameLBL.Width;
        if (destW >= 260)
        {
            destWmax = 260;
            DestNameLBL.AutoSize = false;
            DestNameLBL.Size = new Size(destWmax, 16);
            DestNameLBL.AutoEllipsis = true;
        }
        else
        {
            DestNameLBL.AutoSize = true;
            destWmax = destW;
        }
```